# Cluster Autoscaler Not Launching m6i.xlarge Instances in EKS Node Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

In our Amazon EKS cluster, we have observed that the Cluster Autoscaler is only launching m6i.large instances and is not considering m6i.xlarge instances for scaling. This issue affects the functionality and resource scaling capabilities of our EKS cluster.

Steps to Reproduce:

Create an Amazon EKS cluster with a node group named "emissary-124-managed" configured as described below:

```bash
- name: xxx-124-managed
  availabilityZones: ["ap-southeast-2a","ap-southeast-2b","ap-southeast-2c"]
  instanceTypes: ["m6i.xlarge","m6i.large"]
  privateNetworking: true
  iam:
    attachPolicyARNs:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/xxxxx
    withAddonPolicies:
      autoScaler: true
      externalDNS: true
      albIngress: true
      cloudWatch: true
  securityGroups:
    attachIDs:
      - sg-xxxxx # SG-1 
  minSize: 1
  maxSize: 20    
  labels:
    nodegroup-type: xxxxx
    k8s.xxxx/nodeGroup: xxxxx
  desiredCapacity: 1
  taints:
    - effect: NoSchedule
      key: k8s.xxxxx/nodeGroup
      value: xxxxxx
```

Expected Behavior:
The Cluster Autoscaler should consider both m6i.xlarge and m6i.large instance types for scaling based on the workload requirements and resource demands.

Actual Behavior:
The Cluster Autoscaler is only launching m6i.large instances, which limits the scaling options and resource flexibility for our workloads.

Additional Information:

Node group configuration includes both m6i.xlarge and m6i.large instance types.
The taints and tolerations have been reviewed, and no specific restrictions are in place that would prevent the launching of m6i.xlarge instances.
Pod scheduling requirements have been checked, and tolerations match taints.

Environment Details:
Amazon EKS Cluster
Kubernetes Version: EKS v1.24
Node Group Configuration: Managed Node Group as provided above

Please help/suggestion to resolve this issue to ensure that both m6i.xlarge and m6i.large instances are considered for scaling by the Cluster Autoscaler, providing the necessary resource flexibility for our workloads.

Comment: Cluster-autoscaler doesn't really support mixed instance pools with instances of varying sizes. `karpenter` is an alternative from AWS that has better support for mixed instance types. "Note that the instance types should have the same amount of RAM and number of CPU cores, since this is fundamental to CA's scaling calculations." - https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md#using-mixed-instances-policies-and-spot-instances